# Error while Formatting Decimal Type node in XML for European format

Tags: xml, xslt, navision

- List item

I am using an XSLT for formatting all my Decimal type nodes to European format in XML.
My XML looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <getPriceRecommendationResponse>
      <status>
        <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
      </status>
      <priceRecommendation>
        <tssArticleNumber>Item Number</tssArticleNumber>
        <compoundCode>T46N</compoundCode>
        <compoundGroupCodeBucket>A</compoundGroupCodeBucket>
        <compoundCodeBucket>T46 &amp; others</compoundCodeBucket>
        <qualityIndexCode>-</qualityIndexCode>
        <qualityIndexBucket>Std Quality</qualityIndexBucket>
        <weight>66.0341</weight>
        <weightGroupBucket>BT 36.2227 and 73.4214</weightGroupBucket>
        <weightIsValidBucket>YES</weightIsValidBucket>
        <subGroupCode>PT</subGroupCode>
        <subGroupCodeBucket>7:B03</subGroupCodeBucket>
        <stockDistinction>MTS</stockDistinction>
        <productIdBucket>Item</productIdBucket>
        <referencePrice>41.9176</referencePrice>
        <averageQuantity>5</averageQuantity>
        <quantityAdjustments>0.77</quantityAdjustments>
        <highDV>2.05792</highDV>
        <averageDV>1.40269</averageDV>
        <lowDV>0.95137</lowDV>
        <additionalAdjustmentsTotal>1</additionalAdjustmentsTotal>
        <highPrice>66.42256189184</highPrice>
        <averagePrice>45.27399672488</averagePrice>
        <lowPrice>30.70694327624</lowPrice>
      </priceRecommendation>
    </getPriceRecommendationResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

My XSLT looks like following

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="decimalformat.xsl"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:decimal-format name="eu" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />
<xsl:template match="*[number()=number()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@*|node(), '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i am getting an error while trying this in my application whereas its working fine in transformation tool. The Error is as follows.

Microsoft Dynamics NAV

A call to System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load failed with this message: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

OK

If i exclude the code

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(@*|node(), '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
```

its not giving the error but of no use.
i have changed it as

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
```

also but same error. Please help me. Thanks

Thank you Martin Honnen, I have tried the code suggested by you, still have the same error. I have seen a similar post which gives more information regarding the error i am getting.
http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/gettingpastthexslterrorexpressionmustevaluatetoanodeset/#comment-484235
I think the issue is the Point mentioned in the blog

```
**However, if you select from a node-set but instead use </xsl:value-of> as a subelement, you get a string, and you can’t later select directly from a string.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaF6 and it works fine, the stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:decimal-format name="eu" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />
<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and number()=number()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result is

```
<Envelope>
   <Body>
      <getPriceRecommendationResponse>
         <status>
            <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
         </status>
         <priceRecommendation>
            <tssArticleNumber>Item Number</tssArticleNumber>
            <compoundCode>T46N</compoundCode>
            <compoundGroupCodeBucket>A</compoundGroupCodeBucket>
            <compoundCodeBucket>T46 &amp; others</compoundCodeBucket>
            <qualityIndexCode>-</qualityIndexCode>
            <qualityIndexBucket>Std Quality</qualityIndexBucket>
            <weight>66,0341</weight>
            <weightGroupBucket>BT 36.2227 and 73.4214</weightGroupBucket>
            <weightIsValidBucket>YES</weightIsValidBucket>
            <subGroupCode>PT</subGroupCode>
            <subGroupCodeBucket>7:B03</subGroupCodeBucket>
            <stockDistinction>MTS</stockDistinction>
            <productIdBucket>Item</productIdBucket>
            <referencePrice>41,9176</referencePrice>
            <averageQuantity>5</averageQuantity>
            <quantityAdjustments>0,77</quantityAdjustments>
            <highDV>2,05792</highDV>
            <averageDV>1,40269</averageDV>
            <lowDV>0,95137</lowDV>
            <additionalAdjustmentsTotal>1</additionalAdjustmentsTotal>
            <highPrice>66,4225618918</highPrice>
            <averagePrice>45,2739967249</averagePrice>
            <lowPrice>30,7069432762</lowPrice>
         </priceRecommendation>
      </getPriceRecommendationResponse>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

The only odd thing about your XSLT is the leading `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="decimalformat.xsl"?>`, that would normally belong in the XML if you want to make use of client-side XSLT.